# Logcat --------- beginning of system

Tags: android, adb, logcat

I am troubleshooting a strange bug, and I'm seeing this in logcat right when the bad behavior occurs.

```
    --------- beginning of system
```

What does this mean? I haven't found any native crash logs, or any exceptions, nothing.  Just this "beginning of system" line right at the exact time my app is bugging out.

Comment: Have you installed `admob`?

Comment: I think `--------- beginning of system` means something like *logs have been cleared, starting new logging session*.

Comment: can you print full log

Comment: --------- beginning of system shows before the generation of system logs and --------- beginning of crash shows before the exception appears in the code

Answer (score 1):

this issue is caused by firebase performance. You can find detailed information here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/perf-mon/get-started-android

my log record is as follows:

```
--------- beginning of system
--------- beginning of main
--------- beginning of crash
12-25 17:53:40.583 25281 25581 D FirebasePerformance: Creating a new Non Verbose Session: 34bf424qwe12312318ac831ad5459a
12-25 17:53:40.584 25081 25081 D FirebasePerformance: Creating a new Non Verbose Session: 642b3efweqwsafqweqa5a73e1befasadcb2e
12-25 17:53:50.872 25181 25881 D FirebasePerformance: onResume(): com.example.app.ui.splash.SplashScreen: 10309636 microseconds
12-25 17:54:27.026 25381 25501 I FirebasePerformance: Did not receive a HTTP Response Code
12-25 17:54:27.026 25081 25201 W FirebasePerformance: Unable to process the PerfMetric due to missing or invalid values. See earlier log statements for additional information on the specific missing/invalid values.
```

your mistake is like mine

Answer (score 0):

If possible print full log in your question or see doc below:

> **Reading a stack trace**
>
> The first step to fix a crash is to identify the place where it happens. You can use the stack trace available in the report details if you are using Play Console or the output of the logcat tool. If you don’t have a stack trace available, you should locally reproduce the crash, either by manually testing the app or by reaching out to affected users, and reproduce it while using logcat.
>
> The following trace shows an example of a crash on a sample app:
>
> ```
>     --------- beginning of crash
> AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> Process: com.android.developer.crashsample, PID: 3686
> java.lang.NullPointerException: crash sample
> at com.android.developer.crashsample.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:27)
> at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6134)
> at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:23965)
> at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6440)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:746)
> --------- beginning of system
> ```

[full doc here](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/vitals/crash)

Comment: In my question i stated theres literally no native crash, or stack trace, nothing.. not even `beginning of crash`

Answer (score 0):

Please check manifest and change Launcher activity
exported false to exported true